# Error when requesting custom columns SA360 api - cannot define custom columns in query select clause without Unrecognized field error

Tags: google-sa360-api

Difficulty requesting custom columns or dimensions in SA360 search stream api query. A standard query might be:

```
`    Select 
     campaign.id, 
     [customcolumn], 
     metrics.clicks 
    from campaign 
    where segments.date = '2023-06-03'`
```

When adding custom columns into the select clause, an `Unrecognized Field` error is thrown.

I've managed to request the custom columns associated with an account with the List CustomCOlumns endpoint:
[https://searchads360.googleapis.com/v0/customers/{customer_id}/customColumns](https://searchads360.googleapis.com/v0/customers/%7Bcustomer_id%7D/customColumns):

```
   ` {
      "name": "SSS", 
      "valueType": "DOUBLE", 
      "queryable": true, 
      "referencedSystemColumns": [
        "metrics.all_conversions", 
        "segments.conversion_action", 
        "metrics.clicks"
      ], 
      "resourceName": "customers/{id}/customColumns/111111", 
      "referencesMetrics": true, 
      "id": "111111"
    }
`
```

Within the documentation for SA360, I can only find information about how to pull information about the custom columns, but not use them in a search stream query.

I've tried a few dozen different combinations of the below with no luck.

```
customcolumns.sss
"customcolumn.sss"
metrics.customcolumn.sss
custom_columns.111111
```

All options generally lead to "Unrecognized field in the query"

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by SA360 support. The custom columns I wanted were created by the Google Ads account. Only columns/metrics created in the SA360 account (i.e., not imported) can be queried as custom elements.